# Error al redirigir muchas veces al usuario

Tags: python, tkinter, tcl

Al redirigir al usuario a la funcion de otro archivo .py me da limite de 3 veces y luego se cierra

Algo asi

Programa > 2do Programa > Vuelvo al programa > 2do programa > Programa >2do Programa > Programa > 2do programa en lugar de ejecutar cierra

los archivos tienen una funcion la cual se llaman entre ellos para ejecutarlos algo asi:

```
def informacion():
    info=Tk()
    #Mas codigo
```

Pero el problema es que al redirigir 3 veces el programa en lugar de redirigir de nuevo se cierra, y esto seria muy molesto para el usuario tener que cerrar la app , abrirla

Encima, es un sistema operativo por lo que por este pequeño error, el usuario tendria que tener la computadora especificamente al lado para  apretar el boton de prendido porque,ahora se cierra porque lo ejecuto, pero cuando sea sistema no se cerraría, se apagaría y bueno, imaginense la molestia

O si no aun mas molesto, configurar de nuevo el boot, seria molesto no solo porque es molesto bootear de nuevo, si no porque  tambien hay gente que no sabe y tiene miedo de modificar y arruinar su computadora

Archivo principal ( main.py )

```
from tkinter import ttk                                                                       
import mouse    
import time
import webbrowser                                                                                
from tkinter import *    
def Motion(event):                                                
    global x_mouse                                                
    global y_mouse                                                
    x_mouse=event.x                                               
    y_mouse=event.y                        
def right_both(event):
    destroyright("che")
    right_click("che")
    None
def destroyright(event):                                          
    rightclick.destroy()                                          
    info_sys.destroy()                                            
    arrow.destroy()                                               
    background.bind("<Button-3>",right_click)                     
def right_click(event):                                           
    global rightclick                                             
    global info_sys                                               
    global arrow                                                  
    rightclick=Frame(root,bg="white",width=300,height=350)        
    rightclick.place(x=x_mouse+1,y=y_mouse+1)                     
    background.unbind("<Button-3>")                               
    background.bind("<Button-1>",destroyright)      
    background.bind("<Button-3>",right_both)                    
    info_sys=Label(root,text="Informacion del sistema",bg="white")
    info_sys.place(x=x_mouse+20,y=y_mouse+10)                     
    arrow=Label(root,text="►",bg="white")                         
    arrow.place(x=x_mouse+280,y=y_mouse+10)                       
    info_sys.bind("<Button-1>",info)          
def _comments():
    webbrowser.open("mailto:foxy77843@gmail.com?Subject=Comentario%20De%20SaDro%20System&body=Mi%20Comentario%20De%20SaDro%20System%20Es ")
    None
def _restart():
    root.destroy()
    time.sleep(0.1)
    main()                                     
def _shutdown():
    exit()                             
def menu_task2(event):                                                                          
    _task.destroy()                          
    task_sadro_1.bind("<Button-1>",menu_task) 
    shutdown.destroy()
    refresh.destroy()   
def menu_task3(event):                                                                          
    _task.destroy()                          
    task_sadro_1.bind("<Button-1>",menu_task) 
    shutdown.destroy()
    refresh.destroy()   
    right_click("Hola")                                              
def menu_task(event):                                                                           
    global _task   
    global shutdown
    global refresh                                                                             
    _task=Frame(root,bg="#313131",width=600,height=500)                                         
    _task.place(x=230,y=root.winfo_screenheight()-555)                                          
    background.bind("<Button-1>",menu_task2)  
    background.bind("<Button-2>",menu_task2)
    background.bind("<Button-3>",menu_task3)     
    task_sadro_1.bind("<Button-1>",menu_task) 
    shutdown=Button(root,text="Apagar",bg="#313131",command=_shutdown)
    shutdown.place(x=230,y=root.winfo_screenheight()-81)  
    refresh=Button(root,text="Reiniciar",bg="#313131",command=_restart)
    refresh.place(x=280,y=root.winfo_screenheight()-81)      
def restart():                                                                                  
    root.destroy()                                                                              
def info(event):                                                                                
    root.destroy()                                                                              
    import system_info
    system_info._info()                                                                       
_TclVersion=TclVersion                                                                          
_TkVersion=TkVersion                                                                            
def main():
    global root
    global background
    global task_sadro_1
    root=Tk()                                                                                       
    root.title("SaDro - Sistema")                                                                   
    root.attributes("-fullscreen",True)                                                             
    background=Frame(root,bg="pink",width=9999,height=9999)                                           
    background.place(x=0,y=0)                                                                       
    taskbar=Frame(root,bg="violet",width=9999,height=50)                                            
    taskbar.place(x=0,y=root.winfo_screenheight()-50)                                               
    task_sadro=PhotoImage(file="C:/ProgramData/sysadro/bin/icons/taskbar/sadro_s.sadroimage")                                                                             
    task_sadro_1=Label(root,image=task_sadro,bg="violet")                                           
    task_sadro_1.place(x=root.winfo_screenwidth()/2-200,y=root.winfo_screenheight()-47)                                            
    task_sadro_1.bind("<Button-1>",menu_task)                                                       
    task_sadro_1.bind("<Button-1>",menu_task)                                                       
    task_sadro_help=PhotoImage(file="C:/ProgramData/sysadro/bin/icons/taskbar/help_icon.sadroimage")                                                                                    
    task_sadro_help_1=Label(root,image=task_sadro_help,bg="violet")                                                   
    task_sadro_help_1.place(x=root.winfo_screenwidth()/2-200+50,y=root.winfo_screenheight()-43)                                                  
    desktop_sys_info=PhotoImage(file="C:/ProgramData/sysadro/bin/icons/sys_info/64.sadroimage")                                                                               
    desktop_sys_info_1=Label(root,image=desktop_sys_info,bg="pink")                                                   
    desktop_sys_info_1.place(x=10,y=10)                                                             
    desktop_sys_info_1.bind("<Button-1>",info) 
    desktop_sys_info_2=Label(root,text="Información del \n sistema",bg="pink")
    desktop_sys_info_2.place(x=0,y=84)                                                    
    background.bind("<Button-3>",right_click)                         
    background.bind("<Motion>",Motion)                                
    root.mainloop()                            
main()
```

Archivo de info de sistema (2do programa)

```
def _main(event):
    info.destroy()
    import destroyroot
    exec("destroyroot")
from tkinter import *
import platform
from typing import TYPE_CHECKING
syst=platform.system()
def _info():
    global info
    info=Tk()
    info.attributes("-fullscreen",True)
    systemVersion="Pre-Alpha 0.1"

    infoFrame=Frame(info,bg="orange",width=9999999,height=9999999)
    infoFrame.place(x=0,y=0)

    TclLabel=Label(info,text=f"Tcl/Tk Version: {TclVersion}")
    TclLabel.place(x=50,y=50)

    TkIconPhoto=PhotoImage(file="C:/ProgramData/sysadro/bin/icons/tk.sadroimage")
    TkIcon=Label(info,image=TkIconPhoto,bg="orange")
    TkIcon.place(x=160,y=45)

    SystemLabel=Label(info,text=f"SaDro Version: {systemVersion}")
    SystemLabel.place(x=50,y=100)

    SystemIconPhoto=PhotoImage(file="C:/ProgramData/sysadro/bin/icons/sadro/sadro64.sadroimage")
    SystemIcon=Label(info,image=SystemIconPhoto,bg="orange")
    SystemIcon.place(x=230,y=76)

    operatingSystem=Label(info,text=f"Sistema operativo : {syst}")
    operatingSystem.place(x=50,y=150)

    taskbar=Frame(info,bg="violet",width=9999,height=50)
    taskbar.place(x=0,y=info.winfo_screenheight()-50)

    close=Frame(info,bg="skyblue",width=9999,height=30)
    close.place(x=0,y=0)
    closeFrame=Frame(info,bg="white",width=50,height=30)
    closeFrame.place(x=info.winfo_screenwidth()-50,y=0)
    closeLabel=Label(info,text="×",font=("Calibri",16),bg="white",fg="black")
    closeLabel.place(x=info.winfo_screenwidth()-32.5,y=-3)
    closeLabel.bind("<Button-1>",_main)
    closeFrame.bind("<Button-1>",_main)
    closeLabel2=Label(info,text="Informacion de SaDro System™",bg="skyblue").pack()

    task_sadro=PhotoImage(file="C:/ProgramData/sysadro/bin/icons/taskbar/sadro_s.sadroimage")
    task_sadro_1=Label(info,image=task_sadro,bg="violet")
    task_sadro_1.place(x=15,y=info.winfo_screenheight()-47)

    task_sadro_help=PhotoImage(file="C:/ProgramData/sysadro/bin/icons/taskbar/help_icon.sadroimage")
    task_sadro_help_1=Label(info,image=task_sadro_help,bg="violet")
    task_sadro_help_1.place(x=60,y=info.winfo_screenheight()-43.5)

    info.mainloop()
```

Comment: Buenas @fourseven, solucionar el problema sin ver el código es algo difícil, sería mejor si adjuntases el código.

Comment: ok, ahora mismo adjunto

Comment: Listo¡! ya adjunte

Comment: ¿No te sale ningún error en la consola cuando se cierra el programa?

Comment: No, redirige 2 veces, se cierra sin error ni aviso.

Comment: Fue solucionado, en system_info.py use el exec() pero queria ejecutar la funciona man()

Comment: ¿Podrías explicar por qué es un _código fuente filtrado_? Aunque edites tu pregunta, aún se puede ver en el historial de modificaciones el código. En todo caso, modifica tu pregunta para abstraer lo más posible el código en caso de que contenga información sensible, y solicita que un moderador _redacte_ (edite) el historial, explicando tu caso a través del enlace de _Reportar_ > _Se necesita la intervención de un moderador_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Archivo system_info.py

```
def _main(event):
    info.destroy()
    import destroyroot
    exec("destroyroot")
```

El destroyroot contiene el codigo que ejecuta main() para evitar importación circular, pero no pasa nada

No queria usar exec(),antes si , lo quise cambiar pero, me olvide cambiarlo en system_info